# Tooltip Dropdown in sharepoint designer / sharepoint 2013 #Beginner

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Did you know how to create dropdown with tooltip in sharepoint form?

Could you please suggest me best way to accomplish this functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can use jQuery code to achieve it, add the code below into a script editor web part in the new/edit form page.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var fieldname="PC Model Required Field";// modify the fieldname
    $("select[title='"+fieldname+"'] option").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("title",$(this).val());
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you modify the fieldname in the code above? I suggest you provide some screenshots about the list form. Yes, we can add the custom value for the dropdown tooltip.

Comment: Modify the fieldname in the code above to "PC Model Required Field".